# Conditionally, Converting of JSON to XML using MuleSoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, datamapper, mule-component, dataweave

I have a simple conversion of JSON to XML using MuleSoft. In "Transform Message" component, I provided **JSON Schema** as Input and **XML Schema** as Output. When I run the app, the conversion happens if the file matches with both schema but it generates an empty XML file if it doesn't match.

**I want below conditions:**

1) If the file matches with schema, the converted output file should be sent to **converted folder** and the original file should move to **Success folder**.

2) If the file doesn't match with schema, the original file should move to the **Failure folder** instead of conversion.

Hope, I explained it comprehensively as I am new to MuleSoft. Here is a sample diagram which may simplify my requirement. Provide me with a new one if I badly designed the process.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to create a flowVar that will hold your original payload.

When your doing your evaluation, if its XML then use a simple XPath expression like `//elementName[not(node())]`

Lastly, on your success use scatter-gather for multi-threading write.  Pull your original payload from flowVar and write to Success and Write your regular payload to your Converted folder